# Is there a workaround to configure host to address mapping on hosts file on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, https, hosts, ipad-2

I need to connect to a work remote server via work VPN (the server is web GUI so connection is via https) which requires hosts resolution, meaning I have to configure the host name and map to the IP address in the hosts file. This is how I connect to the remote server on my Mac.

I just got a new iPad 2020 and I will like to connect to the server on my iPad.

For me to access the hosts file on iPad, I will have to jailbreak of which I don’t wanna do that. I’ve read counts of articles online on how to go about using some other apps, but it only works for if your server and your device are both on thesame network and VPN is not used.

Appreciate if there is a workaround for me to do this:
I need to connect via work VPN;
Access the server using the host name on safari etc.

Thanks.

Comment: For software use, configuration, and admin-type questions, the odds are that you will get better answers on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The VPN configuration should ensure that dns requests are handled by your work dns server. That dns should have the correct name resolution entries. You should not need to edit a hosts file.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for replying... the DNS does the resolution but that’s from within the server. When accessing the server itself, the requirement is to have the hostname to ipaddress resolution done using the hosts file.

Comment: What I am saying is that your VPN should provide an appropriate DNS that allows your device to find the server. Host files should not be required. If sounds like your administrator has not set things up correctly.